# behaviour of accessibiility service on events

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

help in understanding the concept of accessibility service in android in its behaviour when the events is stopped also can the accessibility service can be stopped or killed. What are the cases when the accessibility service is killed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

No, accessibility service can't be killed by the user.
It can only be turned off from the accessibility settings or via other provided stopping ways.
Android developer site says:
"
The lifecycle of an accessibility service is managed exclusively by the system and follows the established service life cycle. Starting an accessibility service is triggered exclusively by the user explicitly turning the service on in device settings. After the system binds to a service, it calls AccessibilityService#onServiceConnected(). This method can be overridden by clients that want to perform post binding setup.

An accessibility service stops either when the user turns it off in device settings or when it calls AccessibilityService#disableSelf().
"

Please let me know if you have more queries on this

Comment: Alternatively, please refer these links for more understanding about accessibility services and accessibility in android:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html